# Getting multimedia versions in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 via the UI

Tags: cms

In the CME (right-click) context menu for a multimedia component, selecting `Versioning` > `History` shows previous versions of the component.

When I open a previous version, I see the component view but with `Save to Disk` grayed out.

[image: Save to Disk Grayed out]

**How would I retrieve old versions of multimedia? Is it possible through the UI?**

I can see the old image but this won't help with documents. I could alternatively roll an old version forward then open that. WebDav seems to open the current version, even if I select an older version of an image.

**Edit**:
Documentation links (login required) describe the steps and suggest being able to view, but not necessarily change, previous versions is the expected behavior. I would think `Save to Disk` would still be okay, though.

- [Version history](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?c=t&action=html&resource=publist_home.html#url=http%3A//sdllivecontent.sdl.com%3A80/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26lang%3D%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dmultimedia%2520history&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1336575441752&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_28DB7A348FE842C5AB1A41A321D241E1&pubid=SDL_Tridion_2011&publang=en-US&resource=8436b515-4c12-4544-bdf7-2b057f1bac83.xml&docid=concept_28DB7A348FE842C5AB1A41A321D241E1&filename=Versioning_history.xml&query=multimedia%2520history&scope=&tid=df4225cb-956c-4a33-9b19-455c327bd483&inner_id=&addHistory=true)
- [Viewing the version history list](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?c=t&action=html&resource=publist_home.html#url=http%3A//sdllivecontent.sdl.com%3A80/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26lang%3D%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dmultimedia%2520history&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1336575441752&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_verhist2DDAFF2CF95E4430AA0F27AD7A91B5F8&pubid=SDL_Tridion_2011&publang=en-US&resource=&docid=task_verhist2DDAFF2CF95E4430AA0F27AD7A91B5F8&filename=Versioning_ViewingHistory.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&inner_id=&addHistory=true)